# Python:: About ploting multiple graphs in one window by using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a python GUI program that gets the values from Arduino and visualizes the graph instantly by using the animation. In this code, I tried to create multiple graphs in total 6boxes like this. [desired design of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WR3m.jpg)

But in this code, only one graph is shown. I've been googled for quite a long time, but there was no kind of examples on google. Can you please advise me on how to create multiple graphs in one window by using matplotlib?

[Code Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQf1a.png)

```py
#referred source from https://pinkwink.kr/1230


#VegaSpace GUI Program


#2021 Mar 9 Version 1 modified by Juwon Lee

#이거 할때는 항상 Arduino Serial 창을 닫아야 함.
#https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_color
#you can access to lots of demos when you scrol it way down.


#box plots
#https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-demo-py
import serial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

#어떻게 글자를 넣을 수있는 지에 대한 자세한 설명
#https://towardsdatascience.com/matplotlib-tips-how-to-add-text-on-plots-33a87bdd7605


arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-AH06YEC3', 9600, timeout = 0.5)
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(2, 3)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('VegaSpace Gyro Output')

#setting the limitation of each value
ax1= plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
ax2 = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
ax3 = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
ax4 = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
ax5 = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
ax6 = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
#여기서 ax는 이름일 뿐 바꿔서 여러개 사용할 수 있다.
gyxline, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)#gyx = ax1
gyyline, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)#gyy = ax2
gyzline, = ax3.plot([], [], lw=2)#gyz = ax3
acxline, = ax4.plot([], [], lw=2)#acx = ax4
acyline, = ax5.plot([], [], lw=2)#acy = ax5
aczline, = ax6.plot([], [], lw=2)#acz = ax6
#title
ax1.set_title('Gyro X Axis', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_title('Gyro Y Axis', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax3.set_title('Gyro Z Axis', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax4.set_title('Accel X Axis', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax5.set_title('Accel Y Axis', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax6.set_title('Accel Z Axis', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
#ax1 axis title
ax1.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=15)
ax1.set_ylabel('Change in Axis', fontsize=15)

#ax2 axis title
ax2.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=15)
ax2.set_ylabel('Change in Axis', fontsize=15)

#ax3 axis title
ax3.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=15)
ax3.set_ylabel('Change in Axis', fontsize=15)

#ax4 axis title
ax4.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=15)
ax4.set_ylabel('Change in Axis', fontsize=15)

#ax5 axis title
ax5.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=15)
ax5.set_ylabel('Change in Axis', fontsize=15)

#ax6 axis title
ax6.set_xlabel('time', fontsize=15)
ax6.set_ylabel('Change in Axis', fontsize=15)



max_points = 50
gyxline, = ax1.plot(np.arange(max_points), 
                np.ones(max_points, dtype=np.float)*np.nan, lw=2, label='Gyro Output' ) 

def init():
    return gyxline,

def animate(i):
    y = arduino.readline()
    #During the decoding from byte to value, eliminate the unnecessary two things placed at last.
    y = y.decode()[:-2]
    #define that y value is float
    y = float(y)
    old_y = gyxline.get_ydata()
    new_y = np.r_[old_y[1:], y]
    gyxline.set_ydata(new_y)
    return gyxline,


def shutdown():
    sys.exit(0)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I want to make change. 2Rows 3Columns image would be this one.

Comment: Please don't paste code screenshots but rather post your code directly.

Comment: Sorry about that..

Comment: I'll add the code right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial / documentation explains precisely how to create multiple subplots: [Creating multiple subplots using `plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html?highlight=subplot)

Simple Example:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
fig.suptitle('Subplots in a 2x3 Grid')
axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 1].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 2].plot(x, y)
axs[1, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[1, 1].plot(x, y)
axs[1, 2].plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! It was so useful. By the way, Is it possible to create different names for "axs"??